# Implement multi column combo box using HTML + JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking a multi columns combo box by using HTML + JavaScript only. Is there any example or library available? As I came across some solution, they are in ASP.NET, but not pure HTML + JavaScript.

Here is an example but it is implemented using Java Swing.

[image]

Comment: Something like http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/ but that shows only the top row unless focused?

Comment: yui datatable could be used inside the combo popup, but it's not a good enough answer to what he's asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If jQuery is an option, here's a plugin that looks like it can deliver this:

[Jquery Multi Column Selectbox](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Forms-and-Controls-C-C/Jquery-Multi-Column-Selectbox-54203.html)

Answer (score 3):

**Flexbox** is probably the best one I have ever used with jQuery, with paging and JSON support :

http://flexbox.codeplex.com/

It's a real **combo box**, as it displays the results by typing. It can be easily restyled through the CSS.

Eg. to modify the rows :

```
.ffb .content .row {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #828790;
    clear: both;
    color: #000000;
    height: 20px;
}
```

`border-bottom` may be removed to get rid of lines between rows.

Comment: I don't the horizontal separator for each row. You know how to make them invisible?

Comment: Is it possible to make Flexbox search on all columns not just the {name} column?

Comment: the site at http://flexbox.codeplex.com/ does not exist anymore

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/combos.html Shows ExtJS's combo box. Their combo box can be customized with template to be used for rendering each entry. All you'd need to do is to specify a template that contains a few spans with a set width.

If you're willing to use ExtJS (not free), write it in here, and I'll show you an example