# Can I style a <select> element to show columns?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a column-based list within a  <select> element with multiple=multiple - what I'd like to see in the menu is:

```
Opt1    Opt5    Opt9
Opt2    Opt6    Opt10
Opt3    Opt7    Opt11
Opt4    Opt8    Opt12
```

Is this possible? I'm certainly open to doing this in jQuery but would prefer CSS.

Comment: This is not possible using the native HTML `select` element. However it would be possible to recreate your example using a `div` which is shown/hidden on click of a controlling input. You may have issues with accessibility using this method - if that is important to you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You should make this an answer; just because the answer is "no" does not mean it's not valid. :)

Comment: You can do ≈anything with jQuery, building custom form elements that sort of look like and sort of behave like native widgets. I personally advise against it, as the end user experience change and loss of functionality is not usually worth adhering to your custom UI desires.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is most definitely possible.

There are several options suggested in [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221439/implement-multi-column-combo-box-using-html-javascript).

And [this very popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195270/professional-jquery-based-combobox-control) takes it a bit further, adding autocomplete.

And if you google "jquery multi-column dropdownlist" you can find several more choices.

BTW, the "`multiple`" attribute specifies whether the user can select multiple items in the list, not whether there are multiple columns displayed in the dropdownlist.

Comment: The "similar question" is kind of different if you have a close look. OP likes to have three columns of options, not three column in the same option.

Comment: @PiTheNumber, that's why I said it is similar, and I didn't say it's a dup. While the questions aren't identical, some of the answers given there would be very helpful here. And, seeing by the votes which were the most popular answers could also be helpful in this situation. That's why I provided this information here, in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible with CSS.

However, you can make three selects and use javascript to make sure just one of them is selected.

Here is a simple example how to do it with jQuery:

```
$('.columnselect').click(function()
{
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.columnselect:not([id="' + id + '"]) option:selected').attr('selected', false);
})
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/eJmgz/

If you like to have multi select just remove the Javascript code.

Comment: All you have to do is click and drag on any/all of the columns and you can select an option in each column. http://i.imgur.com/gAB8v.jpg

Comment: That is why it's a _simple_ example ;) There are also 13 other ways to manipulate this select. You have to validate the data in your app anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The [jQuery gentleSelect plugin](http://shawnchin.github.com/jquery-gentleSelect/) does exactly what you're looking for :-)  http://shawnchin.github.com/jquery-gentleSelect/

It makes it really easy to render Select and MultiSelect elements in multiple columns/rows, and gives you complete control over the layout and design. Much easier than trying to do this in CSS ;-)

Answer (score 2):

No – you can not style the select drop downs using just CSS (there are a few exceptions for Google Chrome) because they are part of the operating system, not the Browser.

You can however use JavaScript (there are a few really good jQuery plugins out there, as this one: [uniformjs](http://uniformjs.com/)) where you essentially hide the original select drop down, and replace it with a <li>-list or another element of your choice – which you can style.