# Very low level HTML issue- Add padding to text in a select option

Tags: html

I am attempting to build a select box with options that require minor formatting and am running into issues.

an example of what I am looking for in an option text:

```
title      (some content)
title-2nd  (other content)
```

And while I have formatted the text in the option elements to look like the text above all my extra spaces seem to be truncated when it is rendered.

actual html:

```
<option value="1">1st Option       (0, 0, 0) </option>
<option value="5">Default Option   (0, 0, 0) </option>
<option value="6">Other            (0, 0, 0) </option></select>
```

Again, when rendered in HTML the spaces are gone and all the text is just aligned left and single spaced.

I know there are javascript replacements for the select, but would like to avoid if possible.

Is there a special char I can use (`&nbsp;` didn't work)

Thanks in advance.  (Hope this made sense)

EDIT: So there have been a few mentioning using javascript components to replace the select, and I do know how that works but would like to avoid it.

Adding some screen shots to show the difference between what I am seeing in jsFiddle and codepen vs what I am seeing locally

[image]

markup

[image]

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I style a <select> element to show columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082492/can-i-style-a-select-element-to-show-columns)

Comment: Pls can you post a screen shot or fiddle?

Comment: can you use &#32; char?

Comment: @AhbapAldirmaz, same result as &nbsp;  I will get a fiddle up in a minute

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195270/professional-jquery-based-combobox-control

Comment: Funny enough $nbsp; works in jsFiddle, but not for me locally

Comment: Well I dont know what is going on.  What I am trying seems to work other places, just for me in my solution, thanks for hte help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form fields are notoriously difficult to style, especially elements like `<select>` and `<option>`.

[MDN - Styling HTML forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Styling_HTML_forms)

your idea to use a special character can work though. you can tabulate the options yourself using em spaces [like so](http://codepen.io/ericjphillips/pen/dMMbzo).

EDIT: too new to comment ^__^

did you define your character set in the header of your HTML?

try adding `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your header. it's likely included in Codepen and JSFiddle. I'm thinking maybe your browser doesn't know your local copy wants to use Unicode characters.

Comment: I see that your solution is working in the code pen, but it is not working locally.  I will add a screenshot to my original question to show what i mean

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try `&#160;` instead of `&emsp;`

[Like this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxxvKz)