# Multi-Column dropdown in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multiple-columns, dropdown

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5.0
Is there anyway to create multi-column dropdown like this?
I don't have any plug-in except jQuery.

[image]

Comment: Sure, there's a way.  It looks like it would involve a bit of custom code.  If you have that page as an example then you can view the page's code and see what it's doing.  Seems like it's floating an element which contains a table and responding to click events on rows of that table.

Comment: I don't, I only used Google Image search to find an illustrated picture.

Comment: I guess you're going from scratch then.  Either way this question is either too broad or looking for recommendations for plugins, neither of which can really be answered here.  I suspect a floated element containing a table is pretty close to the implementation being used here, so you can at least start there I suppose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implement multi column combo box using HTML + JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221439/implement-multi-column-combo-box-using-html-javascript)